# How to pass data from one activity to another without using intents

Tags: android-intent

I have two activities lets say A and B.
I have two Edittext on A. I am inputting numbers in both edittext and I want to display which number is greater in second activity in Textview. **But I don't wish to use intent over here.**

Comment: This can't possibly be urgent :-( You need an `Intent` to start the second `Activity`, so you just put the contents of the 2 `EditText` fields in the `Intent` and send them to the second `Activity`. Why don't you want to do it that way?

Answer (score 0):

If you really can't put the data in the `Intent` (and I don't understand why you can't do that), just use 2 `public static` variables that you declare in the first `Activity` and set to the content of the 2 `EditText` fields. The second `Activity` can then access the data by using `FirstActivity.firstVariable` and `FirstActivity.secondVariable` or whatever. It is ugly, but should work.